# Rock, Paper, Scissors Program - Java

Tags: java

I need to write a program that accepts user input and generates a computer choice. I am only allowed to generate the computer choice by using
int compVal = (int) (3*Math.random()) +1;
The user must enter r, p, or p.

My struggles are when I move onto the if statements. I can't use the user choice in the if statement because it's not an Int. I have looked at the different programs on the web and they haven't help me at all. I also have to convert the user input into a capitol case letter with to.Upper.

I guess I just need some help getting started.

Comment: Please take the tour and read the help center.

Comment: We can't really remark on your if statement, or other code, because you didn't post it.

Comment: `I can't use the user choice in the if statement because it's not an Int.` What? Just convert the computer choice to a string representation or the user choice to the integer representation.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the users input and then assign it some value depending on what they enter.

For example:

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
    userValue = 1;
}
```

Alternatively using this you could just process their input in the if statement.

For more info on that method look here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm

Answer (score 1):

Convert user's r/p/s input into 1/2/3 or some similar values